# Moving an object on the x axis based on relative position of mouse

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 2D game in the Unity engine with C#. I have a player object that moves up on the y axis consistently, and i want to have the player steer it by dragging the cursor on the screen (think of swiping in mobile devices).

I've tried something already, but i have to drag all the way to the edge of my screen to get my player to the edge of the camera view. How do i improve the controls so the player follows the position of the mouse on the x axis? 
Thanks.

```
if (moving == true)
    {
        Vector3 mouse Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = new Vector3(mouse.x, transform.position.y, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating a variable that stores the position on mouse click, and the position of the player.
Then move the player relative to the position.

This is what you could possible do: (This could be improved)

```
Vector3 mouseStartPosition;
Vector3 playerPosOnMouseClick;
if(Input.GetButtonDown(KeyCode.Mouse0){
    mouseStartPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    playerPosOnMouseClick = transform.position;
}

if (moving)
{
    Vector3 currentMousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector3 newPosition = playerPosOnMouseClick + (mouseStartPosition - currentMousePosition);
    transform.position = new Vector3(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, 0);
}
```